# How to use Elm in a JS file using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elm

I'm trying to implement some Elm code in a JS file using React. I have never experienced programming with Elm before and I want to know how to work this situation out.

using "elm" in a terminal makes it not recognizable in a command.
"react-elm-components" does not support Elm.Main.Embed 
Specifically, embed is not recognized as well as default.a.Main is undefined
Even if I fix this, the Webpack is not recognized in the compiler.

```
'use strict';
import Elm from "react-elm-components";
const node = document.getElementById('app');

// Update the second argument to `Elm.Main.embed` with your selected API.
// See `doc/intro.md` for more information.
const app = Elm.Main.embed(node, {
    api: 'Client',
    hostname: 'localhost:3000',
});

app.ports.startTimer.subscribe((int) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        app.ports.timeout.send(int);
    }, 10000);
});
```

TypeError: react_elm_components__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.Main is undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of undefined

Expected: Should print out diagram of nodes.